# Why is the System process listning on 80/443?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

How come that the system process (pid 4) is listning on all :443 and :80? that means that only IIS can listen to those ports. not visualsvn for example (of course different IP's)

```
  >netstat -aon
  ...
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  ...
```

i tried to disable the HTTPS traffic in rule and even disable the whole firewall, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default IIS (and its HTTP.sys driver) will listen on ALL IP addresses configured on the server (including any new ones added while it is running).  If you want to have IIS listen only on specific IP addresses (and leave others alone for other servers that need to use port 80 as well), you will need to define an IP Inclusion List (also called an IP Listen List in some places).

In Windows Server 2003, use the HTTPCFG.EXE utility from the command line.  There is a [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781601%28WS.10%29.aspx) that describes the specifics on the commands to use to do this.

For Windows Server 2008, use the [NETSH utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Justin. Here's a kb article for it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954874

Answer (score 2):

I vote for WinRM, as i saw that before. Shut ws-management to check. Process explorer would help on that too